# Expanding PCI slots beyond original motherboard

Tags: motherboard, pci-express, expansion

Do machines exist with PCI(-e) slots and nothing else, which I could then connect to my main machine through an external port e.g. USB-C?

The idea is that if I put too many video cards in my computer (and even just two can take up a lot of space), I no longer have slots for anything else, and I have quite a few other PCI(-e) cards that I want to be using.

Is this a thing and if not how hard would it be to fashion it?

Comment: No; what you want does not exist

Comment: Are you asking about PCI slots or PCIe slots? The title of your question has PCI but is tagged with pci-express. And in your question, you have used PCI(-e), and I simply cannot understand which one it refers to.

Comment: Refers to either one. Probably PCIe would be a better answer since anything new I would get would be PCIe, and I only have one PCI card which, with my motherboard setup, I can just move over a slot if I only add one other vidcard.

Answer (score 0):

You can buy [*PCIe expanders*](https://www.google.com/search?q=pcie+expander) that, for example,  take a single 8-[lane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express#Lane) (x8) PCIe slot and connect it to an external chassis containing 8 slots - each 1 lane (x1).

This doesn't increase the number of lanes available but can help rearrange them into a format that allows better use of slots and thus allows you to use more PCIe cards than your PC has PCIe slots.

Comment: Interesting concept. I did that search and most of what I found were hubs, typically with multiple 1x going into one 1x.